# How to read pixel of 2 canvas on top of eachother?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to get the pixeldata (like getImageData()) of an area where are 2 canvasses at top of eachother. The canvas on top has a transparancy so you have combination of colors.
Is this possible to get the result what is cohorent with the eye? Or is it with a work-around possible? Thanks

Comment: You can only read data from each individual canvas - you'd have to do two reads, and then manually calculate what the overlapping result should be if it were one value.

Comment: Combining 2 colors into 1 **visually appropriate** color is not easy--I haven't found a satisfying method yet.